# No Matching Names in people picker, but browse dialog works just fine

Tags: people-picker

I'm making a user control for a master page, and I want to include a People Picker (PeopleEditor) control for selecting a single user that will be associated with the control. Everything is coming out fine for the intial rendering, but I'm having issues finding people through the Check Names functionality that are not happening in any other people picker.

Clicking on "Check Names" underlines a name provided, saying no exact match found, etc, then I click and it says "`<No Matching Names>`":

[image: "No Matching Names" after "Check Names"]

If, however, I click on the "Browse" button and enter the exact same text in the search field there, I get the correct result to select:

[image]

Other People Pickers on the site work fine; I haven't done anything special to configure this one:

```
<SharePoint:PeopleEditor runat="server" SelectionSet="User" ID="EditContactPeoplePicker" MaximumEntities="1" ValidatorEnabled="true"/>
```

Any suggestions on things I need to specify, set, or check on?

**EDIT**

I have since done a bit more searching and discovred that it does work on some pages, but does not work on other pages (being on the masterpage, I can only guess that some pages load something into context that allows the picker to function, and other pages do not... I have yet to find a pattern...) still searching... When I get an hour or so, I might come back with a list of the pages that do and do not work, but there are higher priorities right now...)

Comment: have you tried with the domain? Maybe you have more than one domain, or the people picker is trying to use a specific authentication, have you tried `ForceClaims=true`?

Comment: If you mean have I tried `DOMAIN\code.jockey`, then yes, I have tried that: it works wherever it works and does not work on the other pages, regardless of what I type in :-/ --- There are multiple domains, but matches come up from both where it works at all... I will try `ForceClaims="True"` when I get back to work on Tuesday, but I am also bound to work around it and force people to use the dialog, since that seems to work well enough :-P - thanks for the suggestion!